# JQuery & Popper how to show calling Element Text

Tags: jquery

In a page with several URL/A Elements, I'd like to show the element text in the popover result.
For example, when I hover with the mouse over A1, I'd like to see the text "This is A1".
Tried several options but would really appreciate a working example.

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    content: '<div>This is ' + 
    $(this).text()
    + ' </div>',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a ng-href="#" data-toggle="popover">A1</a>
<br>
<a ng-href="#" data-toggle="popover">B2</a>
<br>
<a ng-href="#" data-toggle="popover">C3</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `function`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/#options

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  content: function() {
    return '<div>This is ' + $(this).text() + ' </div>'
  },
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover'
});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a ng-href="#" data-toggle="popover">A1</a>
<br>
<a ng-href="#" data-toggle="popover">B2</a>
<br>
<a ng-href="#" data-toggle="popover">C3</a>
```